# Properties of function $F(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ such that $ \sqrt{u^2+v^2}\geq M\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $M$ be a positive real number and $u,v:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be continuous functions satisfying $$\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\geq M\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$$ Let $$F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$$ be given by $$F(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$$ Which of the following statements are true ?

$1.$ $F$ is injective .

$2.$ $F$ maps open sets to open set .

$3.$ $F$ maps closed sets to closed set .

$4.$ if $E$ is closed and bounded then $F^{-1}(E)$ is also closed and bounded.

I don’t know exactly how to solve it . I tried counter for first option as $F(rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta)=(r,0)$ and one thing which is also clear that inverse image of bounded set is also bounded as by given inequality measure distance from origin to range and domain points . How to think about image of closed and open sets and inverse images ?  Is there any theorem? Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clever enough to fully know what you've written actually means, but I do know a little, which might be helpful. I think it is the case where $M$ $=$ $2$. It may or may not be useful.

But if you define  $y$  as  ($v$ $+$ $u$)$/$$2$ and $x$ as ($v$ $-$ $u$)/$2$, then $v$$^2$ + $u$$^2$
is exactly equal to $2$ ($y$$^2$ + $x$$^2$), i.e.

$v$$^2$ + $u$$^2$ $=$ $2$ ($y$$^2$ + $x$$^2$)

I'm not sure this helps much, but maybe it's a start.

Comment: You forget about the square root. And u=Mx, v=My would be enough.

Comment: @joebloggs I didn’t get it